Simple solution in Delphi for wildcard search, on strings with asterisk
I would like to implement a simple search form for users, on a list of strings. Assume here that users are familiar with wildcards in general, but not with Regular Expressions.
This is of course trivial to do using the TMask:
uses
  masks;

procedure search(mystring: string);
var
   M: TMask;

begin
   M:= Tmask.create(mystring);
   try
      // some action if matches
      // loop code skipped here

      if M.Matches(Myform.content) then 
        Myform.found := true;
   finally
      M.Free;
   end;

end;


This is working as expected.
But how do I make a search for strings containing literal * and ? characters ? Say, I want to find a string which is either *** or *****  ? A search pattern of ***?? will match anything, just like a single *, so this will also find ABCDEF.
Is it better to make a DIY solution based on regex in background, or is there an alternative simple wildcard library ?

You can use a unitary set to escape reserved chars as [*][*][*]??
link

I would have a radiogroup like this:

(and perhaps a "case sensitive" and/or "word search" checkbox)
and then either call the M.Matches or POS(MyString,MyForm.Content)>0 (with or without .ToUpper)
based on the selection.
You have to let the user decide if these characters are literal or special - you can't deduce it yourself.

Personally, I'd have three checkboxes ("Case sensitive", "Word search", and "Use wildcards (* and ?)").

@AndreasRejbrand: That's also an option - I like the radio group better, because it is more informative. YMMV.

I did not think of the totally obvious "pos()" solution.  This will be initial way. Next improvement could be to subclass masks, so mask characters can be selected.
